# How can I access the next value in a collection inside a foreach loop in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, foreach

I'm working in C# and with a sorted `List<T>` of structs. I'm trying to iterate through the `List` and for each iteration I'd like to access the next member of the list. Is there a way to do this?

Pseudocode example:

```
foreach (Member member in List)
{
    Compare(member, member.next);
}
```

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You can't. Use a for instead

```
for(int i=0; i<list.Count-1; i++)
   Compare(list[i], list[i+1]);
```

Comment: This code is going to throw an index out of bounds exception for list[i + 1] on the last iteration of the loop...

Comment: @froadie that's what the -1 after Count is for

Comment: @Bob and froadie: teh -1 after the Count won't prevent the exception on list[i+1].  The Count - 1 just adjusts for the zero-based index.

Comment: @Addie - @munissor makes a good point.  While some of the syntax niceities are all well and good, it is something easier (and makes more sense) to use the good, old-fashioned syntax.

Comment: @JMarsch - the < instead of a <= adjusts for the zero-based index. The additional -1 takes care of exception on list[i + 1]

Comment: @Jason - thanks for the support ;) In those cases I also think that old-fashioned syntax is easier to use and read..

Comment: I approve of the elegance of this method. It's interesting to see how caught up people get in all the tools that exist and forget the simple things.

Comment: This is fine, of course. As long as the collection in question implements IList<T>

Comment: @froadie - gotcha -- I missed the < (vs <=)

Comment: We need to process the last record seprately

Answer (score 27):

You could just keep the previous value instead:

```
T prev = default(T);
bool first = true;
foreach(T item in list) {
    if(first) {
        first = false;
    } else {
        Compare(prev, item);
    }
    prev = item;
}
```

Comment: This solution is better than mine if list is a ICollection or IEnumerable because you can't index the sigle elements of the list.

Comment: What about T prev = T[0]?

Answer (score 9):

If one were so inclined, you could probably write an Extension method for this as well...

```
public static void ForEachNext<T>(this IList<T> collection, Action<T, T> func)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < collection.Count - 1; i++)
        func(collection[i], collection[i + 1]);
}
```

Usage:

```
List<int> numList = new List<int> { 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15 };

numList.ForEachNext((first, second) => 
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}, {1}", first, second));
});
```

Answer (score 5):

Use a regular for loop with an index, and compare list[i] and list[i+1]. (But make sure to only loop until the second-to-last index.)

Or, if you really want to use a foreach, you can keep a Member reference to the previous member and check the next time around. But I wouldn't recommend it.

Answer (score 4):

[LINQ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query) might be your friend here. This approach will work with anything that's IEnumerable<T>, not just IList<T> collections, which is very useful if your collection never ends or is otherwise calculated on-the-fly:

```
class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        var list = new List<Int32> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
        foreach (var comparison in list.Zip(list.Skip(1), Compare)) {
            Console.WriteLine(comparison);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static Int32 Compare(Int32 first, Int32 second) {
        return first - second;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
XmlNode root = xdoc.DocumentElement;
XmlNodeList nodeList = root.SelectNodes("descendant::create-backup-sets/new-file-system-backup-set");

for (int j = 0; j < nodeList.Count; j++ )
{                
    for (int i = 0; i <= nodeList.Item(j).ChildNodes.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        if (nodeList.Item(j).ChildNodes[i].Name == "basic-set-info")
        {
            if (nodeList.Item(j).ChildNodes[i].Attributes["name"].Value != null)
            {
                // retrieve backup name
                _bName = nodeList.Item(j).ChildNodes[i].Attributes["name"].Value.ToString();
            }
        }
```

Comment: This way u can iterate through the nodelist instead using foreach loop..use for loop. Instead of individual XmlNode we can use the NodeList itself

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by IndexOf but FYI IndexOf get the first item equal to the item so if you have a lot of items with the same value it's better to use for loop instead or define the range of search. Official docs are [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.indexof?view=net-7.0)

```
foreach (Member member in List)
{
    var nextItem = List[List.IndexOf(member)+1];
    Compare(member, nextItem);
}
```