# How to compare current item with the next item in foreach asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, foreach

I have a question.

I have model, and I show in the page this model thanks to foreach. And in the model I have column (`vPeriod`) and I need to compare current item (e.g `vPeriod = 2016`) with next item (e.g. `vPeriod = 2017`) and I don't know how to compare!

```
foreach(var item in Model)
{
if(current.vPeriod == next.vPeriod)
{
//do something
}
else
{
//do something
}
}
```

If I use `for`, it's the easy way. But how do I do this with `foreach`?

Code view:

```
 <tr class="line2">
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td style="color: #5f6877;">2016</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>

@foreach (var itemData in Model)
            {
                if (itemData.vPeriod == "2016")
                {
                    <tr class="line3">
                        <td>@itemData.vAddress</td>
                        <td>@itemData.vCreateDate</td>
                        <td>@itemData.iCountOfFloors</td>
                        <td>@itemData.iCountOfRooms</td>
                        <td>@itemData.iAreaOfRooms</td>
                        <td>@itemData.vLastRepairs</td>
                        <td>@itemData.vType</td>
                        <td>@itemData.vBelonging</td>
                        <td>@itemData.vPlanRepairs</td>
                    </tr>
                }
            }

            <tr class="line2">
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td style="color: #5f6877;">2017</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>


            @foreach (var itemData in Model)
            {
                if (itemData.vPeriod == "2017")
                {
                    <tr class="line3">
                        <td>@itemData.vAddress</td>
                        <td>@itemData.vCreateDate</td>
                        <td>@itemData.iCountOfFloors</td>
                        <td>@itemData.iCountOfRooms</td>
                        <td>@itemData.iAreaOfRooms</td>
                        <td>@itemData.vLastRepairs</td>
                        <td>@itemData.vType</td>
                        <td>@itemData.vBelonging</td>
                        <td>@itemData.vPlanRepairs</td>
                    </tr>
                }
            }
```

It's like really awful! I can have many different years and all the time need to create a block with data and a `foreach block for year.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2404193/how-can-i-access-the-next-value-in-a-collection-inside-a-foreach-loop-in-c

Comment: Okay. But i have problem, when I use for. I write `for(int i = 0; i < Model.Count();i++)` and after that I can't to call the item with `Model[i].vPeriod` it's not work.

Comment: Ofc, because first, you have to cast your collection to an array. var newArray = Model.ToArray(); 
Also, don't' forget to check if the next value isn't outside of array boundaries.

Comment: in your view code, its not clear whats difference between the 2016 and 2017 cases? what do you want to do exactly?

Answer (score 5):

You can't access the next element using `foreach` loop. Rather you should use `for` loop and on the basis of array index you can compare the two values. Use something like this

```
for(int i=0; i<Model.Count-1; i++)
{
   list[i] != list.Last() ? Compare(list[i], list[i+1]) : break;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Good effort but there is a possibility of `Index out of range exception` when `i` reaches last value. This `list[i+1]` will be the cause of exception.

Comment: could you modify to:
list[i] != list.Last() ? Compare(list[i], list[i+1]) : break;

Comment: I think the programmer would have and idea of if else. By the way i have changed the code @Morgan

Answer (score 4):

Solution with for:

```
var array = Model.ToArray();
for (int i = 0; i < array.Length - 1; i++)
{
    if(array[i].vPeriod == array[i + 1].vPeriod)
    {
        //do something
    }
    else
    {
        //do something
    }
}
```

Solution with foreach, adjust prev type to your needs:

```
    string prev = string.Empty;
    bool first = true;
    foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        if (first)
        {
            first = false;
        }
        else if (prev == item)
        {
            //do something
        }
        else
        {
            //do something
        }

        prev = item;
    }
```

Comment: the `for-each` solution seems good. Although, the `for` solution will not take last item! (it may cause problems depending on what he wants to do)

Comment: OP wants to compare every item with next item and we don't know what should be done with the last item. So the default assumption is to ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
int counter = 1;
foreach(var item in Model)
{
    if(counter == Model.Count)
       {
           break;
       }
    if(item == Model[counter])
       {
           //do something
       }
    else
       {
           //do something
       }
    counter++;
}
```

Comment: Please, tell me this is a joke.

Comment: It's stupid, I know. But the person asked to be with a foreach and I wrote it for him with a foreach.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all. I did it. I did new combined model and used loop for. I think, it's posible variant to answer.

Code model:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace NarkomApp.Models
{
    public class Repairs_RepairsPeriodModel
    {
        public List<REPAIRS> repairsModel { get; set; }
        public List<REPAIRS_PERIOD> repairsPeriodModel { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Code view:

```
 @for (int i = 0; i < Model.repairsPeriodModel.Count; i++)
            {
                <tr class="line2">
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td style="color: #5f6877;">@Model.repairsPeriodModel[i].vPeriod</td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>

                for (int j = 0; j < Model.repairsModel.Count; j++)
                {
                    if (Model.repairsPeriodModel[i].iIdRepairsPeriod == Model.repairsModel[j].fk_iIdRepairsPeriod)
                    {
                        <tr class="line3">
                            <td>@Model.repairsModel[j].vAddress</td>
                            <td>@Model.repairsModel[j].vCreateDate</td>
                            <td>@Model.repairsModel[j].iCountOfFloors</td>
                            <td>@Model.repairsModel[j].iCountOfRooms</td>
                            <td>@Model.repairsModel[j].iAreaOfRooms</td>
                            <td>@Model.repairsModel[j].vLastRepairs</td>
                            <td>@Model.repairsModel[j].vType</td>
                            <td>@Model.repairsModel[j].vBelonging</td>
                            <td>@Model.repairsModel[j].vPlanRepairs</td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                }
            }
```

In the end, I have good table with data:)