# Get col[0] values while col[1] is equal to previous col[1] iteration

Tags: c#, .net, arraylist

I'm using a rate sheet from the US fed reserve site, which contains two cols
[0] == ShortDate (ex "1/1/1962")
[1] == Rate for that date in [0]

So the file looks like: **1/1/1962,3.8**

Each time this utility runs, it gets/opens the file, removes all data for dates On and Before 5/31/1997. It then writes to a stream (in my case, another csv file) with the following headers: **rowid,beginningdate,expirationdate,rate**

The problem I have is, part of the requirement is that if the rate (col [1]) has the same value for some consecutive days, then don't list those days specifically. Instead, write the date of the first consecutive rate, then write the last date before the rate changes again.

My problem/question is:

How do I check against each iterated col[1] value before and after during a loop so I can write correct the beginning and expiring dates? I was hoping to bump the index of a value by one so I could get the values in the next row, but having a hard time doing that even.

I've tried my research at using as many Linq-based queries I could but I can't find anything that works and just need another pair of eyes / another idea.

Here is what I'm doing so far:

```
int count=0;
var rateContents = File.ReadAllLines(resFile);
List<DateTime> lstDT = new List<DateTime>();
List<string> lstRate = new List<string>();
List<string> d = new List<string>();

foreach (var x in rateContents)
{
   lstDT.Add(Convert.ToDateTime(x.Split(',')[0]));
   lstRate.Add(x.Split(',')[1]);
}

int recordsOn_and_after6_1_97 = lstDT.Where(z => Convert.ToDateTime(z) >= Convert.ToDateTime("6/1/1997")).Count();
int recordsbefore6_1_97 = lstDT.Where(z => Convert.ToDateTime(z) < Convert.ToDateTime("6/1/1997")).Count();
lstRate.RemoveRange(0, recordsbefore6_1_97);
lstDT.RemoveRange(0, recordsbefore6_1_97);

using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(desktoppath + "somefile.csv"))
{
   while (count <= (recordsOn_and_after6_1_97 - 1))
   {
    //sw.WriteLine("Index Number,Effective Date,Expiration Date,Rate");
    d.Add(Convert.ToDateTime(lstDT[count].ToShortDateString()) + "," + lstRate[count]);
    count++;
   }
}

count = 0;
/*Below is where I am stuck. Realistically I think I'd want to do something like: var variable = argh.val[count+1]; or something, but I can't get that to work either. I'm missing something simple at this point.*/
foreach (var argh in d.Select((val, ind) => new { Value = val, Index = ind}))
{
   //var curdt = Convert.ToDateTime(argh.Split(',')[0]).ToShortDateString();
   //var currate = argh.Split(',')[1].ToString();
   var curdt = argh.Value.Split(',')[0];
   var currate = argh.Value.Split(',')[1];
   var x = currate.CompareTo(currate[count + 1].ToString()).ToString() ;
   Console.WriteLine(x.ToString());
   //Console.WriteLine("val +1: " + curdt + " --- rate: " + currate.TakeWhile(z => z <= 10).ToString());
   count++;
   //Console.WriteLine(prevcurdt +" --- "+ currate);
}
```

Please be gentle, I'm still learning new things dang near daily :-)
Thank you!

Comment: I did find a post just now on SO that looks like it's in the same realm of my problem. I'm going to give it a shot. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2404193/how-can-i-access-the-next-value-in-a-collection-inside-a-foreach-loop-in-c

Comment: When you say "the last date /before/ the rate changes again", does that mean if you have, say May 1.1, Jun 1.1, Jul 1.2, the expiration date of 1.1 is Jun or Jul?

Comment: @steve16351, If the Rate is 1% for May 1 but the Rate for May 2 is 1.5%, they'd be separate entries on the spreadsheet. If days June 1, June 2 and June 3 all have a Rate of 2%, then the beginningday would be 6/1/yyyy and the expirationdate would be 6/3/yyyy , hope that makes a little more sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my idea to filter the rates as you want them. Basically just a simple for loop which looks at the rates either side of the current one - if the next rate isn't the same, we know the current date is the expiration date of whatever entry we're currently on. If the last rate isn't the same, we know it's a new entry.

```
public class RateEntry
{
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime ExpirationDate { get; set; }
    public decimal Rate { get; set; }
}

class Program
{

    const string DATE_FORMAT_IN = "yyyy-MM-dd";
    const string DATE_FORMAT_OUT = "yyyy-MM-dd";

    static void Main()
    {
        var inputRateDataRaw = File.ReadAllLines(@"c:\temp\RATES_IN.csv");

        DateTime startDate = new DateTime(1997, 05, 31);

        // parse the input dates and rates
        var rateDataFiltered = inputRateDataRaw
            .Select(rateData =>
            {
                var dataComponents = rateData.Split(',');
                DateTime rateDate = DateTime.ParseExact(dataComponents[0], DATE_FORMAT_IN, null);
                decimal rate = decimal.Parse(dataComponents[1]);
                return new RateEntry() { StartDate = rateDate, Rate = rate };
            })
            .Where(a => a.StartDate > startDate)
            .OrderBy(a => a.StartDate)
            .ToList();            

        List<RateEntry> rateRanges = new List<RateEntry>();

        for (int i = 0; i < rateDataFiltered.Count; i++)
        {
            RateEntry next = ((i + 1) == rateDataFiltered.Count) ? null : rateDataFiltered[i + 1];
            RateEntry last = (i == 0) ? null : rateDataFiltered[i - 1];
            RateEntry now = rateDataFiltered[i];
            // if this is the first rate, or if the last rate isn't this rate, this is a new entry.
            if (last == null || last.Rate != now.Rate)                
                rateRanges.Add(now); 
            // if the next rate isn't this one, then the current entry expiration is this one's start date.
            if (next == null || next.Rate != now.Rate) 
                rateRanges.Last().ExpirationDate = now.StartDate; 
        }

        // write the data out
        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"c:\temp\RATES_OUT.csv"))
        {
            writer.WriteLine("ROWID;STARTDATE;EXPIRATIONDATE;RATE");

            for (int i = 0; i < rateRanges.Count; i++)
            {
                RateEntry rateEntry = rateRanges[i];
                writer.WriteLine($"{i};{rateEntry.StartDate.ToString(DATE_FORMAT_OUT)};{rateEntry.ExpirationDate.ToString(DATE_FORMAT_OUT)};{rateEntry.Rate}");
            }
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
};
```

Comment: Ah man, that's brilliant! I know comments aren't for "thanks", but.. thanks! I learned how to do more stuff because of you, and it works well. I'm going to accept your answer :-)